# Use SQL to Replace Multiple Commas in a String with a Single Comma

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Input: **Hi,,How are you? Fine, thanks ,, ,  ,,,, , James,Arden.**

I would like to replace all consecutive commas with a single comma and a space.

The output should be:

**Hi, How are you? Fine, thanks, James,Arden.**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hi,,How are you? Fine, thanks ,, ,  ,,,, , James,Arden.', ',,+', ', ') FROM DUAL;
```

I haven't tested it yet as I don't have access to the Oracle system yet.

Comment: Take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/28054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simple solution with same output:

```
Hi, How are you? Fine, thanks, James, Arden.
```

@Joseph B: Sorry I can not comment yet! So I post my answer here.

```
SELECT 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            REGEXP_REPLACE('Hi,,How are you? Fine, thanks ,, ,  ,,,, , James,Arden.', ', | ,', ','), --Replace ', ' and ' ,' with ','
        ',{1,}', ', ') single_comma_text --Replace one or more comma with comma followed by space
FROM DUAL;
```

You can check this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/28075)

Comment: Great. How can I return those records that have consecutive commas two or more eg ,,? regardless of the spaces between them: ,   ,

Comment: Replace all space between commas, then use REGEXP_LIKE in WHERE clause to check if the String have 2 or more consecutive commas, ignore space: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(REGEXP_REPLACE(multi_commas_column, ', | ,', ','), ',{2,}')`. Check this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/28101)

Comment: @user311509: Could you please accept this answer? This will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query ...

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            REGEXP_REPLACE('Hi,,How are you? Fine, thanks ,, ,  ,,,, , James,Arden.', ', | ,', ','), --Replace ', ' and ' ,' with ','
        ',{2,}', ', '), --Replace 2 or more occurrences of comma with single comma followed by space
    ',(.)', ', \1') single_comma_text --Replace comma followed by any character with comma followed by space followed by character
FROM DUAL;
```

to get the following output:

```
Hi, How are you? Fine, thanks, James, Arden.
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/28065)**.

**References**:

1. [REGEXP_REPLACE on Oracle® Database SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)
2. [Multilingual Regular Expression Syntax on Oracle® Database SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix001.htm#BABJDBHB)